# Enumeration class no Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, repository, dapper

Como posso ler do meu banco um atributo `int` que no meu sistema é um atributo de tipo `Enumeration` no `Repository Pattern`?

Eu fiz uma classe:

```
public class Status : Enumeration
{
    public static readonly Status Active = new Status(0, "Active");
    public static readonly Status Inactive = new Status(1, "Inactive");
    public static readonly Status Removed = new Status(2, "Removed");

    public Status()
    {
    }

    private Status(int value, string displayName)
        : base(value, displayName)
    {
    }
}
```

Logo na classe `Bank` coloquei um atributo de tipo `Status`;

Na hora de ler do banco onde minha classe `Bank` e uma tabela com um atributo `Status` tipo `int`, mas o atributo fica `null`.

Como posso resolver isto?

Comment: Só reforçando qual é esse código da leitura?

Comment: `Como posso ler do meu banco um atributo int que no meu sistema`, na sua pergunta tem isso, por acaso além desse código tem o código que recupera as informações contidas no banco ?

Comment: Não entendi o que você entende por código da leitura. Utilizo ADO.net com Dapperpository

Comment: Tem sim tenho uma classe Service que chama ao metodo GetAll do Repository

Comment: @Daniel coloque esse código especifico da sua pergunta?

Comment: public IEnumerable<BankViewModel> GetAll()
        {
                return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BankViewModel>>   (_bankRepository.FindAll());
        }

Comment: só que quando eu faço a leitura tirando o Mapper o seja se faço _bankRepository.FindAll() ele ja não traz o Status, ent~eo descartei o Mapper como problema, acho que o problema esta que o enum é de tipo classe que herda de Enumerable

Comment: passe esse pacote por favor Dapperpository, o nome certinho?

Comment: MicroOrm.Dapper.Repositories baixei do NoGet

Comment: estava lendo os comentários é `Enumerable` ou `Enumeration`???, porque até pensei que fosse algo do Dapper, mas, não encontrei nada. Apesar que não faz muito sentido mesmo utilizar assim

Comment: Como está o método para buscar no banco? Aproveitando, o banco contém os valores inteiros?

Comment: @Randrade é do tipo `int` sim no banco, o problema que deveria ser usado um `Enum`, mas, ele quer traduzir isso em uma classe que herda de um `Enumeration`, usa camada Dapper repository. Parece que isso não é muito válido e não funciona parece.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Aceitar eu tenho quase certeza que não aceita. Minha dúvida era apenas para saber como realmente está fazendo. O [próprio GitHub do pacote mostra um exemplo de como fazer isso](https://github.com/phnx47/MicroOrm.Dapper.Repositories). Porém, gostaria de entender se ele estava fazendo algo além do que está na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obrigado pelas mensagens, já resolvi o problema.

Crie na classe que herda de Enumeration o seguinte:

```
public class Status : Enumeration
{
   //YOUR CODE

  **public static Status FromInteger(int value){
    switch(value){
      case 0: 
        return Active;
      case 1: 
        return Inactive;
      case 2: 
        return Removed;
      default: 
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
  }**
}
```

Então na classe Bank fiz o seguinte:

```
public class Bank {

   //Standard fields that are mapped to a table in database 

   public Status StatusEnum {
     get {
        Status.FromInteger(StatusId); //StatusId is a property mapped to table's field
     }

     set {
        //TODO Handle null value
        StatusId = value.Value;
     }
   }
}
```

Acrescentando além um atributo StatusId que é o tipo atributo do banco e fico joia.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver utilizando o Entity Framework ele automaticamente identifica, ou seja, salva como int no banco e cria o objeto com a enumeração. O que te indico a fazer é trocar essa enumeração pra algo assim:

```
public enum Status
{
    Active,
    Inactive,
    Removed
}
```

Saiba que enums não são salvas no banco, ele vai ser uma coluna int da tabela que possui o enum como propriedade.

Comment: Eu sei nesse caso funciona só que eu estou aplicando o exemplo que postei acima que na teoria deve funcionar tambem

Comment: Acredito que tratar o enum como herança para uma classe faça o Entity(estou supondo que você use o EF) computar que seja um relacionamento, por isso a propriedade está vindo null. Mas ai já não sei bem.

Comment: Não estou usando EF estou usando Utilizo ADO.net com Dapperpository